# Wordpress $wpdb->get_results(...) issues with comparing strings

Tags: php, wordpress, phpbb3

I am trying to iterate through the rows in a phpbb table called phpbb_posts and extract each entry in phpbb's "post_subject" column and compare its value with a predefined string in Wordpress PHP file but I am having some issues - the expressions don't evaluate to true.

My phpBB's tables are installed in WP's database so I have full access to the values.

See the code below to demonstrate the issue I am having.

```
function matchPhpBBTopic()
{
  global $wpdb; 

  $wp_post_title_string = get_the_title();

  $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM phpbb_posts"); 

  foreach($result as $row)
  {      
    $phpbb_post_title_array   = array($row->post_subject);  
    $phpbb_post_title_string  = implode("", $phpbb_post_title_array);

    // One of the values in $row->post_subject contains
    // the value in $wp_post_title_string
    if (strcmp($wp_post_title_string, $phpbb_post_title_string) == 0)
    {
      // This line never runs but the $wp_post_title_string value
      // is there, in the table, I've printed it and it's there
      echo 'We found a match!<br>';
    }                                                                              
  }  
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

So in other words, I have a topic posted in WP and I have **exactly** the same topic posted in phpBB and I want to iterate through the phpBB's table and when I find the topic, I want to run some code. I don't understand why the "if" expression does not run.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do:

if ($wp_post_title_string == $phpbb_post_title_string) {}

I don't think strcmp() is appropriate. It converts the string to encoding numbers.

https://www.php.net/strcmp

Also check for lower and upper case, spaces, and different encodings.

Do strtolower() and trim() first and see what you get.

Also looks like you're imploding subject and title, so don't think they'll match.

Comment: Hey, yes I actually tried == as well as ==== and trim(). I *know* the value is there in the table because I print out the values (just now shown in the above example). So $wp_post_title_string contains "Test" and $phpbb_post_title_string contains "Test". No spaces, no different character case and yet I can never get it to return true. I don't know why. I even tried strpos() and it doesn't find the string, it's weird.

Comment: But here is the weirdest part, if you do strpos($wp_post_title_string, "Test"), that would return true but if you do strpos($wp_post_title_string, $phpbb_post_title_string) even though $phpbb_post_title_string contains "Test", it returns false. What is going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: Read through the first two lines in the foreach loop. You're creating an array and then imploding an array. Try var_dump the two values as you enter the loop and then die. You'll see exactly what they are. You could probably do something like if ( $wp_post_title_string == $row['post_subject']) Remove those first two lines in the loop. When you do the var_dump you'll probably find that the one variable is still an array, or undefined because you're using object notation on what is likely an array.